# Cartesian product filtering with purrr::cross_n

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying out some `purrr` idioms - particularly functions that loop (or apply if you prefer) functions through through one data.frame and compare to all other rows in another data.frame... and filter the cartesian product based on that comparison function..

```
> df1    
        chr start   end
      (fctr) (int) (int)
    1   chr1  9069  9176
    2   chr1 10460 11368
    3   chr1 34633 35625
    4   chr1 36791 37023
> df2
     chr start2
  (fctr) (dbl)
1   chr1  9169
2   chr1 10360
3   chr1 34633
```

So a simple example function is:

```
> is.between <- function(x1, y1, y2){
  ifelse(x1 >= y1 & x1 <= y2, TRUE, FALSE)
}
```

The result I am looking for (for now) should be a 2 by 4 data.frame `df3` like

```
             # desired result
             chr start  end  start2
          (fctr) (int) (int)
        1   chr1  9069  9176  9169
        2   chr1  34633 35625 34633
```

Naively then I have tried to use the `purrr::cross_n` function like so...

```
> cross_n(list(df2$start2, df1$start, df1$start), .filter = is.between)
```

Of course that doesn't work it is searching through the cartesian product of the 3 input columns (48 combinations). I am wishing to search through combinations of `df2$start2` vs [`df1$start` and `df1$end`] (12 combinations).

And so ...Is there a way to do this within the `purrr` framework?

Can't quite get it with `cross_n` or `cross2` and errr.. I don't totally understand the docs on `cross_d`

Comment: I don't see this as a problem that is improved by `purrr`. I would recommend looking at `data.table::foverlaps()`

Comment: @DMC thx that looks interesting but `is.between` is just an example. My real interest is in this **type** of control of cartesian combinations. If an elegant solution exists I could use it in many places.

Comment: Is there a difference between `ifelse(x1 >= y1 & x1 <= y2, TRUE, FALSE)` and vanilla `x1 >= y1 & x1 <= y2`?

Comment: @Frank Nope. I just thought that was a clear example.

Answer (score 1):

OK FWIW - I have adapted some of `purrr::cross_n` function to answer my own question. The new function `cross2d` looks like this:

```
# this makes sense only if the .l in the same groups are the same length
# ie they are probably from the same data.frame
cross2d<- function(.l, groups = NULL, .filter = NULL){
  if (is_empty(.l) | is.null(groups)) {
    return(.l)
  }
  if (!is.null(.filter)) {
    .filter <- as_function(.filter)
  }

  n <- length(.l)

  #separate df for each group
  df1<- data.frame(.l[groups==0])
  df2<- data.frame(.l[groups==1])


  exp.coords<-expand.grid(1:nrow(df1), 1:nrow(df2))
  df<- data.frame(df1[exp.coords$Var1,], df2[exp.coords$Var2,])
  names(df)<-c(colnames(df1),colnames(df2))

  df[do.call(.filter, unname(df)),]
}
```

With the example data `df1` and `df2` and the `is.between` function shown above you use it like so:

```
> cross2d(list(x1=df2$start, x2=df1$start, y2=df1$end), group=c(0,1,1), .filter=is.between)
       x1    x2    y2
1    9169  9069  9176
3.2 34633 34633 35625
```

I have coded this for 2 groups (data.frames really) and data.frame output .. but it mayeb possible to generalise further...?